# Should I worry about (after running ~/.local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh) "Command '' not found, but can be installed with:..."" (Ubuntu Desktop)?

Tags: python, shell, prompt

I am running into a problem following this tutorial:

https://docs.python-guide.org/dev/virtualenvs/
It tells me to run "source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh"
but since it does not exist, updatedb and locate report it is at:
"~/.local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh"

So running into this issue seems to stop me from going forward:

```
charles@lamborghini:~$ source ~/.local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh

Command '' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install bpfcc-tools   # version 0.8.0-4, or
sudo apt install mailutils-mh  # version 1:3.5-2build1
sudo apt install mmh           # version 0.4-2
sudo apt install nmh           # version 1.7.1-4

virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks.

If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON= and that PATH is
set properly.
charles@lamborghini:~$ echo $VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON

charles@lamborghini:~$
```

Should I worry? mkvirtualenv works OK.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed:

```
charles@lamborghini:~/project_folder$ VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=$(which python3)
charles@lamborghini:~/project_folder$ source ~/.local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/charles/.virtualenvs/premkproject
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/charles/.virtualenvs/postmkproject
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/charles/.virtualenvs/initialize
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/charles/.virtualenvs/premkvirtualenv
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/charles/.virtualenvs/postmkvirtualenv
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/charles/.virtualenvs/prermvirtualenv
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/charles/.virtualenvs/postrmvirtualenv
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/charles/.virtualenvs/predeactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/charles/.virtualenvs/postdeactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/charles/.virtualenvs/preactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/charles/.virtualenvs/postactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/charles/.virtualenvs/get_env_details
charles@lamborghini:~/project_folder$
```

Comment: This is the right answer. You should accept it although you are the op as well.